# Binary Search using Recursion

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion

```
    public static int binarySearch(double[] arr, int low, int high, double inq){
    int mid = (low + high)/2;
    if(arr == null) return -1;
    if(low > high) return -1;
    if(arr[(int)inq] < arr[low])
    return -1;
    if(arr[(int)inq] > arr[high])
    return -1;
}
```

I am suppose to search through the array *arr* recursively to find the index of *inq*. All I have is the termination cases. Not sure how to go about this problem.

The original question is this one:

search the array slice `arr[low:high]` for an occurrence
of inq. If inq occurs in arr, return an index i such that
`arr[i] == inq`. Otherwise, return -1. Assume that arr is sorted in increasing order.

And these are the answers to some cases:

The input array is table = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 }.

- 2 was found in table[0:6] at index 0
- 3 was found in table[0:6] at index -1
- 4 was found in table[2:6] at index -1
- 12 was found in table[2:5] at index 5

I know how to do it using iterations, but I am new to recursive methods. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: if you know which part you need to search in just ask `binarySearch` to search in that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to update the search range by updating `low` and `high` by passing the modified `low` and `high` into the next recursive call. Each call, we update the search range to either `[low, mid-1]` or `[mid+1, high]` depending on comparison between `inq` and `arr[mid]`

This will work:

```
public static int binarySearch(double[] arr, int low, int high, double inq){
    int mid = (low + high)/2;
    if(arr == null || low > high) return -1;

    if(arr[mid] == inq) return mid;

    if(arr[mid] < inq) { // inq is in the upper half
        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, high, inq);
    }
    if(arr[mid] > inq) { // inq is in the lower half
        return binarySearch(arr, low, mid-1, inq);
    }
}
```

Comment: You made this make perfect sense to me. Thanks it works flawlessly.

Comment: Glad to help :) Recursion can be hard to wrap heads around in the beginning.

Comment: Tell me about it... It is brain wrecking for me to think recursively when iterations are so convenient, but this makes sense to me. So thanks again for the help